# nohup not logging in nohup.out

Tags: python, logging, web2py, nohup

I am running a python script of web2py and want to log its output. I am using following command
`nohup python /var/www/web2py/web2py.py -S cloud -M -N -R applications/cloud/private/process.py >>/var/log/web2pyserver.log 2>&1 &`

The process is running but it is not logging into the file. I have tried without nohup also but it is still same.
The default logging of nohup in nohup.out is also not working.
Any suggestion what might be going wrong?

Comment: Doesn't web2py have a logging module?

Comment: Check is there enough disk space available? In my case when disk is full it stop logging and when i delete some files then it start logging again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to worry. Actually the python process along with nohup was logging the file in batch mode and i could see the output only after quite some time and not instantaneously.

Comment: That's what I expected from the question :) might as well accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

nohup will try to create the file in the local directory. Can you create a file in the folder you are running it from ?

Comment: yes i can create a file. File permissions are working fine. Everytime i run it creates a file in home directory but is never logged.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got commas in your print statements there's a good chance it's due to buffering. You can put a sys command (forget which) in your code or when you run the nohup, just add the option -u and you'll disable std(in|out|err) buffering

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about this, it is because of the buffering mechanism, run your Python script with the -u flag will solve the problem:

```
nohup python -u code.py > code.log &
```

or just

```
nohup python -u code.py &
```